# Avr Problem: in spi, spdr register is 8 bit but my number is 16 bit

Tags: c, avr, spi, atmelstudio, atmega16

I work with atmega16, in both side master and slave. 
I want to send a number between 100-999 that entered by keypad to the slave. 
Numbers are 16 bit, but spdr register is 8 bit, so I send first lsb then msb bits. This works well and I send my number correctly.

But my problem is in slave side:
I enabled interrupt spie in slave side so each spdr received from master took as a interrupt and goes to ISR function. But because of my number is 16 bit, I want to take each 16 bit or two byte as a interrupt. What should i do?

Comment: Ideally, you should get two interrupts on the slave side -  one for each byte. Why not just save them to a buffer and increment a count to see how many have come?

Comment: In slave side, i while() i have a function that operate, i want to do a ISR function when two byte recived. Not when one byte recived. When i enable interupt in spi automaticly in avr spi interupt ,when one byte recived it goes to ISR. I wanna do something that when two byte rcived it goes to ISR.

Comment: Depending on the specific micro-controller you are using, you might be able to set a transfer size of 16 bits in the SPI peripheral configuration, not sure if the one you are using allows this. Another alternative would be to use DMA (again, if possible on your device) to copy bytes from SPI DR to a buffer and program it to give an interrupt after two bytes are received. I still don't understand what stops you from processing two SPI RX interrupts separately, though!

Comment: Also, please try to frame your question better and if possible, provide code and better context so people find it easy to understand your question.

Comment: Master side send a 16 bit number. For example999, my spdr register in atmega32 is 8 bit so i divide my 16 bit number to two 8  bit pack and send it in two step. It is ok in master side. In slave side a function that i in while(1) is showing number in 7segnent by segment(number) function. I want segment() do always but when a 16 bit number recived it change. So i enabled interupt and write a ISR function. But each 8 bit goes to ISR.  Can i user for(i=0,i<2,i++) date[i]=spdr and merge bites???

Comment: Please share your whole code as part of the question, it will enable more people to help you. Check the answer below, which is roughly what I have been suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know your message length (16 bit or 2 byte). Just create a ring buffer to store two bytes and fill the ring buffer. Maybe you can add a third byte as start or end byte or something else but this is up to you. Additional you set a flag if your transmission ends.

So your code can look like this. Note this code is only the ISR and for an XMega as SPI slave but it should help to understand the procedure.

```
#define SPI_BUFFER_SIZE                     2
uint8_t SPI_RxSlaveBuffer[SPI_BUFFER_SIZE];

typedef struct 
{
    uint8_t* RxBuffer;
    uint8_t BytesProcessed;
    uint8_t Status;
} SPI_Buffer_t;

static SPI_Buffer_t SlaveBuffer;

int main()
{
   // Some code
   SlaveBuffer.RxBuffer = SPI_RxSlaveBuffer;
   // Some other code
}

ISR(SPIC_INT_vect)
{
    SlaveBuffer.RxBuffer[SlaveBuffer.BytesProcessed++] = SPIC.DATA;

    if(SlaveBuffer.BytesProcessed >= SPI_BUFFER_SIZE - 1)
    {
        SlaveBuffer.BytesProcessed = 0x00;
        SlaveBuffer.Status = 0x01;
    }
}
```

You can also check the state of the `SS` pin and reset the counter if the pin is asserted by the master (in case that the master has aborted the transmission or something else) - for example with polling the `SS` pin or wiring the signal of the `SS` pin to an interrupt pin to generate an additional I/O interrupt.

Comment: You don't seem to allocate memory for `uint8_t* RxBuffer`. Why not use an array instead?

Comment: I allocate the memory in my code but it is just missing in this example. I have added it to avoid missunderstandings. This example is part of a bigger code from me where I set the address of the buffer with an function to swap the buffer.

Comment: The idea about using an interrupt for the trailing edge of `SS` is good and should be elaborated. It gives the OP the single interrupt per transmission.

Comment: But you can´t use an trailing edge interrupt on the `ATmega16`, which the OP is using, because the pin isn´t an interrupt pin. You can see it when you check the data sheet. It is an old MCU and so not every pin can used with interrupts. This microcontroller only has three pins for external interrupts. So you only have the SPI interrupts and the polling of the `SS` pin :(

Comment: @thebusybee you can use one interrupt pin as non-hardware `SS` pin and start a non-interrupt based receive on the slave. So you don´t use the SPI interrupts and only one GPIO interrupt and handle the whole SPI communication in the GPIO ISR. But this solution will block all other interrupts until the SPI communication is done. But this would be a solution too.

Comment: @Kampi Once I wired an incoming signal on two pins to let both rising and falling edges trigger interrupts.

Comment: @thebusybee yes, this is a more practical way to detect the end of a transmission. I think I would use both ways: SPI interrupts and the GPIO interrupt to detect the transmission end. So you have a full interrupt based solution to receive your messages and your slave can sleeping all day long until a message is send :)